# Generic extension method for automapper

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods, automapper

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class City:Entity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class BaseViewModel:IBaseViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class CityModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

my domain and view classes...

and

for mapping extension

```
public static TModel ToModel<TModel,TEntity>(this TEntity entity)
    where TModel:IBaseViewModel where TEntity:IEntity
{
    return Mapper.Map<TEntity, TModel>(entity);
}
```

and i am using like below

```
City city = GetCity(Id);
CityModel model = f.ToModel<CityModel, City>();
```

but its long

can i write it like below?

```
City city = GetCity(Id);
CityModel model = f.ToModel();
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because the 1st generic argument can't be implicitly inferred.

I would do this

```
    public static TModel ToModel<TModel>(this IEntity entity) where TModel:IBaseViewModel
    {
        return (TModel)Mapper.Map(entity, entity.GetType(), typeof(TModel));
    }
```

Then the code is still shorted than it was:

```
var city = GetCity(Id);
var model = city.ToModel<CityModel>();
```

Answer (score 15):

Instead of jumping through all of those hoops, why not just use:

```
public static TDestination ToModel<TDestination>(this object source)
{
    return Mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
}
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, I just did a quick test with mapping an object graph with several nested entities 1,000,000 times in a loop in LINQPad.  There was no discernible performance difference whatsoever.

Comment: I've used this approach for a while now, and it works great. But the static API is now obsolete in AutoMapper.

Comment: Note: the static API is not obsolete anymore

Answer (score 0):

Put the extension method on `IEntity` as a member method. Then you have to pass only one type.